# Regex to retrieve the last few characters of a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Regex to retrieve the last portion of a string:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump

I'm looking to retrieve the string followed by `id=`

The following regex didn't seem to work in python 
sampleURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump"

```
re.search("id=(.*?)", sampleURL).group(1)
```

The above should give me an output:

```
com.lima.doodlejump
```

Is my search group right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody has mentioned `urlparse` yet...

```
>>> s = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump"
>>> urlparse.urlparse(s)
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='play.google.com', path='/store/apps/details', params='', query='id=com.lima.doodlejump', fragment='')
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)
{'id': ['com.lima.doodlejump']}
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)['id']
['com.lima.doodlejump']
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(s).query)['id'][0]
'com.lima.doodlejump'
```

The HUGE advantage here is that if the url query string gets more components then it could easily break the other solutions which rely on a simple `str.split`.  It won't confuse `urlparse` however :).

Comment: +1 This is the right way of doing it and this has to be accepted.

Comment: @thefourtheye -- I thought so :).

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression

```
(.*?)
```

will not work because, it will match between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible (becasue of the `?`). So, you have the following choices of RegEx

```
(.*)      # Matches the rest of the string
(.*?)$    # Matches till the end of the string
```

But, you don't need RegEx at all here, simply [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string like this

```
data = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump"
print data.split("id=", 1)[-1]
```

**Output**

```
com.lima.doodlejump
```

If you really have to use RegEx, you can do like this

```
data = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump"
import re
print re.search("id=(.*)", data).group(1)
```

**Output**

```
com.lima.doodlejump
```

Comment: I'd use `data.rsplit("id=", 1)[-1]` unless I had already confirmed that `id=` is in the string. Well, or `split` depending on what behavior I wanted for multiple `id=` appearances. But the OP should think about what the desired behavior there is - using [-1] to avoid an IndexError if it's not present is the important thing.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Ya. That's better. Updated it :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just split it in the place you want:

```
id = url.split('id=')[1]
```

If you print `id`, you'll get:

```
com.lima.doodlejump
```

Regex isn't needed here :)

However, in case there are multiple `id=`s in your string, and you only wanted the last one:

```
id = url.split('id=')[-1]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> import re
>>> sampleURL = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lima.doodlejump"
>>> re.search("id=(.+)", sampleURL).group(1)
'com.lima.doodlejump'
>>>
```

Instead of capturing non-greedily for zero or more characters, this code captures greedily for one or more.